# Positioning div at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website where the menu it should be the end of the page.
Besides the menu, another div with two images should also sit at the bottom of the page.

Follow [the link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/34/) to the complete source code of the page;

In red, the menu should be aligned at the bottom of the page, aligned to the center of div#leftcontent.

In the div#blue social-networks must be aligned at the bottom of the page, aligned to the center of the div#nav.

When I say bottom, I mean right at the end of the page.

Comment: if you're free to change the html (an not only the styles), why don't you create a container on it's own wrapping #leftcontent and #nav, then below insert a new container holding #footer and #social-networks?

Comment: I did not understand, are you saying to create a div to wrap # footer and # social networks? and aligns them to the bottom of the page?
Would have an example?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ is a phenomenal resource.  It sticks the footer to the bottom of the page using pretty simple html and css.  For instructions on how to use it, http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html